# Icons not working with company-box-mode and lsp-mode

Tags: emacs, company-mode

I am having a hard time getting icons to appear in company box mode.

This is what I get with company box mode off:

[image]

And with company box mode enabled I get:

[image]

My setup for lsp looks like this:

```
    (use-package lsp-mode
      :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
      :init
      (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")  ;; Or 'C-l', 's-l'
      :hook ((js-mode . lsp-deferred))
      :config
      (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t))
```

My company set up looks like:

```
(use-package company
  :after lsp-mode
  :hook (lsp-mode . company-mode)
  :bind (:map company-active-map
         ("<tab>" . company-complete-selection))
        (:map lsp-mode-map
         ("<tab>" . company-indent-or-complete-common))
  :custom
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  (company-idle-delay 0.0))

(use-package company-box
  :hook (company-mode . company-box-mode))
```

Edit -- I also thought I should mention that I am using the all-the-icons package.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `company-box-icons-alist` to `company-box-icons-all-the-icons`